# Single custom view multiple shape animation

Tags: android

If a custom view has several shapes, Is it possible to animate only one of them?
For eg: for one of my application, 2 circles, one inner and another outer are drawn on a custom view. While I tried to animate using scale animation, I see that both the circles gets animated where as I need only one of them to. 
One of the solution that occurred to me is to have multiple custom views.
But not sure if it is the right way to do it.
Are there alternate better solution to it?

```
activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.test.customanimation.CustomView
    android:id="@+id/circular_progress"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/scale_up"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Scale Up"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/scale_down"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:text="Scale Down"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private CustomView mCustomView;
private Button mScaleUpBtn;
private Button mScaleDownBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mCustomView = findViewById(R.id.circular_progress);

    mScaleUpBtn = findViewById(R.id.scale_up);
    mScaleUpBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mCustomView.scaleUpAnimation(5000);
        }
    });

    mScaleDownBtn = findViewById(R.id.scale_down);
    mScaleDownBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mCustomView.scaleDownAnimation(5000);
        }
    });

   }
}

CustomView.java

public class CustomView extends View {
private Paint OuterCirclePaint,InnerCirclePaint;

float mCircleX,mCircleY,mInnerCircleRadius,mOuterCircleRadius;

public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int 
defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int 
defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init();
}

private void init(){
    OuterCirclePaint = new Paint();
    OuterCirclePaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    OuterCirclePaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
    OuterCirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    InnerCirclePaint = new Paint();
    InnerCirclePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    InnerCirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    mCircleX = getWidth()/2;
    mCircleY = getHeight()/2;

    if(mCircleX < mCircleY) {
        mInnerCircleRadius = (getWidth() / 2) - 100;
        mOuterCircleRadius = (getWidth() / 2) - 40;
    }
    else {
        mInnerCircleRadius = (getHeight() / 2) - 100;
        mOuterCircleRadius= (getHeight() / 2) - 40;
    }


canvas.drawCircle(mCircleX,mCircleY,mOuterCircleRadius,OuterCirclePaint);
canvas.drawCircle(mCircleX,mCircleY,mInnerCircleRadius,InnerCirclePaint);
}

public void scaleDownAnimation(int duration){
    ScaleAnimation fade_in = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f,0.5f,1.0f,0.5f,
         Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
    fade_in.setDuration(duration);
    fade_in.setFillAfter(true);
    this.startAnimation(fade_in);
}

public void scaleUpAnimation(int duration){
   ScaleAnimation fade_out = new ScaleAnimation(0.5f,1.0f,0.5f,1.0f,
       Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
   fade_out.setDuration(duration);
   fade_out.setFillAfter(true);
   this.startAnimation(fade_out);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already overriding `onDraw()` and providing your own methods to handle the animations. IMO this approach is best for performance, so I'd keep it that way and only switch over to another animation framework, namely [Property Animations](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation)

In order to redraw only the inner circle during an animation, I'd suggest using `ValueAnimator` and `ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener` for the animations.

Let's introduce some new fields for `CustomView`

```
private float scaleFactor = 1f;
private ValueAnimator scaleUpAnimator;
private ValueAnimator scaleDownAnimator;
private ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener updateListener;
```

Initialize them as follows

```
private void initAnimations() {
    scaleUpAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.5f, 1.0f);
    scaleDownAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1.0f, 0.5f);
    updateListener = new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            scaleFactor = (float)animation.getAnimatedValue();
            CustomView.this.invalidate();
        }
    };
    scaleUpAnimator.addUpdateListener(updateListener);
    scaleDownAnimator.addUpdateListener(updateListener);
}
```

Change the line for the inner circle in `onDraw()`

```
canvas.drawCircle(mCircleX, mCircleY, mInnerCircleRadius * scaleFactor, innerCirclePaint);
```

... and start the animations like this

```
public void scaleDownAnimation(int duration){
    scaleDownAnimator.setDuration(duration);
    scaleDownAnimator.start();
}

public void scaleUpAnimation(int duration){
    scaleUpAnimator.setDuration(duration);
    scaleUpAnimator.start();
}
```